# Ошибка: InvalidOperationException: out of sync

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
     Dictionary<Rigidbody, float> cubes_ = new Dictionary<Rigidbody, float> ();
...          
               foreach( var cube in cubes_.Keys){
                    if (cube.gameObject.layer != LAYERS_AND_TAGS.D_2)
                        cube.AddForce ( -Physics.gravity * cube.mass );
                    else{
                        if (DCB.INSTANCE.DCC.IS_GROUNDED == false) {
                            cube.AddForce ( -Physics.gravity * cube.mass * cubes_[cube] );
                            cubes_[cube] = Mathf.Clamp01 ( cubes_[cube] + 5f * Time.fixedDeltaTime );
                        } else
                            cubes_[cube] = 0f;
                    }
                }
```

cubes_ содержит 3 обекта.
При первом заходе в for cube содержит null, при втором первую переменную  из cubes_ (переход в cube.AddForce ( -Physics.gravity * cube.mass ))

При третьем заходе, вторая переменная приводит к выполнению: cubes_[cube] = 0f;
И все, дальше ошибка:

> InvalidOperationException: out of sync
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[UnityEngine.Rigidbody,System.Single].VerifyState
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:912)
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[UnityEngine.Rigidbody,System.Single].MoveNext
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:835)
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection+Enumerator[UnityEngine.Rigidbody,System.Single].MoveNext
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:1028)
>   Magnit.FixedUpdate () (at
>   Assets/Units/Rooms/P_3/Maп/Scripts/Mag.cs:41)

В чем может быть причина ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это

> При первом заходе в for cube содержит null,

противоречит строчке

```
if (cube.gameObject.layer ...
```

Ну ладно.

---

Вы итерируете по ключам словаря, используя энумератор. Внутри цикла Вы меняете свойство объекта-ключа, что приводит к изменению значения, возвращаемого его методом `GetHashCode`. После этого Вы обращаетесь к словарю - устанавливаете значение по изменившемуся ключу. Это приводит к изменению коллекции, по которй Вы итерируете, что не допускается.

```
foreach(var cube in new List<Rigidbody>(cubes_.Keys)){
```

Comment: Спасибо за разьяснение! "При первом заходе в for cube содержит null" - да, неверно написал. Когда (стрелка)/(указатель текущей операции) в первый раз указывает на foreach, то следующий шаг перебрасывает ее не в цикл а в его конец, и после этого из конца стрелку перебрасывает снова на foreach.